Clarification of variableFilter in .OpenModelica.Scripting.simulate
I need a clarification about using variableFilter. I only need like 3 variables from my simulation. I want modelica to only output those variables as a csv file. I know the default is .* which outputs all the variables. I only need to select 3, so I was thinking of using variableFilter = x\[.*\] . I am a little confused about the syntax, but would it be variableFilter = x\[.*\ line1.C, cableTemp.T, commercialCable.l]? Thank you for the help.


I guess like this: variableFilter = "line1.C|cableTemp.T|commercialCable.l"

The implementation uses regex library: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html
